# jwt-decode + popper.js is not working in the application

Tags: angular, npm, bootstrap-4, jwt, popper.js

I am using bootstrap 4 in my applications , for the drop down I have installed the popper.js dependency. I have a use case where I have to decode the JWT token obtained from the API . To decode the JWT I am using the jwt-decode dependency

[jwt-decode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode)

When I use the jwt-decode dependency the popper.min.js deletes from the node_modules and throws the error in the console[image: popper js error]

if I install the popper.js dependency it throws the console error
[image: jwt-decode]

how to use popper.min.js and jwt-decode in the application .

Angular.json

```
"scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/raphael/raphael.min.js",
              "node_modules/select2/dist/js/select2.full.min.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
```

Comment: When you are trying to install jwt-decode, does it uninstall the popper from node_modules? Have you checked their github issues? For testing purpose, only try their CDN version in the app and see if it works?